hiding TikZ definitions inside a namespace
I'm writing a package that I hope to eventually release, which will contain a lot of tikz macros. It will contain a few styles with short names like box, and I'm hoping that I can hide those inside the pgfkeys hierarchy so as not to pollute the global namespace.
What I'm imagining is that there might be a key /my package/box, and the user can use it with something along the lines of
\begin{tikzpicture}[my package]
   \node[box] at (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

However, I can't seem to work out how to do such a simple thing. Here is an MWE for one of my attempts, but it fails with I do not know the key '/tikz/box', so it's evidently not looking inside the /tikz/my package namespace.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    my package/.style = {}, % without this it complains about the key /tikz/my package not existing
    my package/box/.style = {
        rounded corners=1mm
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[my package]
   \node[box] at (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

I'm not attached to the package being used in exactly this way - the code above is just an example. What I'm looking for is the "right way" to make my package easy to use while avoiding potential name clashes.

You are looking for scoping or encapsulation? // Do you write a class, see e.g. The Latex Companion? I'm not sure, whether or not a class in itself frovides that. However you could: a) use TIKZ object oriented approach https://tikz.dev/oo (well: sort of), b) use a fancy prefix for your styles.

If you want the my package style to do something it needs to do something. It doesn't automatically define all styles that are in the namespace below. Maybe my package/.style={box/.style=…}} to create a style box in the namespace currently selected when /tikz/my package is called. Make it my package/.style={/tikz/box/.style=…}} if you want it to always define /tikz/box even if my package is not called in the /tikz namespace, e.g. \pgfset{/tikz/my package}.

If you want to avoid clashes you will need to use a different namespace (though, neither PGF/TikZ nor all the third-party libraries to a good job on this). You could define /tikz/my package/box and make /tikz/box a shortcut only with a special style so that your official box is still available (especially internally) if the user messes with /tikz/box. But that would also mean that /tikz/box/.append style does not apply to /tikz/my package/box. Make your user use my package/box if you want it to be clean.

Lastly, we could do a .search also=/tikz/my package to the /tikz search algorithm (might need to be done manually since /tikz/.unknown does already some fancy things). This might not be a good idea.

Based on your MWE, you want the [mypackage] key to install styles into the current scope. I do that with a style that adds styles. For instance:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    my package/.style = {
        box/.style = {
            draw,
            rounded corners=1mm
        }
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[my package]
   \node[box] at (0,0) {box};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

If your example is much, much bigger, there might be some performance hit from installing these styles over and over. In that case, maybe you could use aliases or another solution.

Here's how to create a LaTeX package that defines box styles while maintaining a clean namespace:
 % mypackage.sty
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    \ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2024/12/05 Custom Box Styles]
    
    \RequirePackage{tikz}
    
    \tikzset{
      /myboxes/.cd,
      .search also={/tikz},
      box/.style = {
        draw,
        rounded corners=1mm,
        fill=lightgray!20
      }
      }
    
    \newcommand{\usemyboxes}{%
      \tikzset{
        /tikz/.cd,
        box/.style={/myboxes/box},
       }
    }

Users can use the package in two ways:
% Method 1: Using full path
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[/myboxes/box] {Content};
\end{tikzpicture}

% Method 2: Using short names after activation
\usemyboxes
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[box] {Content};
\end{tikzpicture}

Full code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mypackage}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[/myboxes/box](0,0) {Content1};
\end{tikzpicture}\\

\usemyboxes
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[box] {Content2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

